# Custom ToolTip in User Control

Tags: c#, tooltip, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm using a custom tool tip style defined in my App.xaml (without a x:key)

```
       <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                        <Grid Background="#001f5b">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OpenStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Opened"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="5"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

but want to use another style in a UserControl.

The problem is that if I define a style in the UserControl, it doesn't override the style from App.xaml (which works for a ScrollBar for example), nor does it work if a style isn't present in App.xaml in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to create a named style (with a Key) in your UserControl and used this key ?